# Thunderbird list email as a bcc

Tags: email, thunderbird

When sending emails to a list from the Address book, it automatically places each address as a "to" making all the addresses visible. I want to automatically address all the emails as a bcc, with only mine being visible. Is there any way to automate this? I have been going through the list and changing each one to bcc.

Comment: +1 for proper use of the Bcc: field! There are several offices in my university who I wish understood this.

Answer (score 6):

1. Select all the contacts you want to add to the current email using Ctrl + Click or Shift + Click.
2. Then right click on any of the selected contacts.
3. Press "add to BCC field"

   [image]

(Image from [Tips 4 pc](http://www.tips4pc.com) )

Answer (score 1):

Two methods are possible, mailing lists or templates.

#### Mailing list

You can just create a new mailing list entry in the address book and set the BCC on the whole list.

1. Open the Address Book
2. File > New > Mailing List
3. Fill out the details of the mailing list as needed, including the emails to send to, but leaving yours off
4. Click **OK**
5. Close the Address Book
6. Compose a new mail message
7. Type up the name of the mailing list you've just created.

   - This will auto-suggest when you start typing
8. Set the mailing list to BCC
9. Add your own email address if you wish to

#### Templates

The other method is to start a new email, but not to send, and then reuse it fully next time.

1. Compose a new blank email
2. Add and set all email addresses as BCC
3. Include your email in the To: field
4. Save the template

Now, when you want to email the list next time, you can just fire up that template and send it off, all the emails already set as BCC with yours included as the only one visible.

Answer (score 1):

I found a MUCH easier way - by accident.

My mailing list is in an Excel SS.  So all I did was go down the list and copy all the email addresses.  Plain Ol' Ctl+C.  Went to the "To:" field in T-Bird changed that to "BCC"  CTL+V.  To make sure you are at the end of your list, hit the "End" key.  Then hit "Enter".

Done, 250 emails that are all BCC in 5 sec.

Of course this only works if you are in Excel, this can easily be done by exporting to a CSV and going from there, but yeah, I found this was much easier than anything I searched for, and I didn't even realize it until I accidentally hit Enter and BAM!

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/use-bcc-instead/ It warns you if a message to more than your defined limit of recipients is going to be sent, and let you change all the recipients to BCC